# Set a timer during reboot

Tags: java, android, boot, shutdown

I'm actually working on ways to reboot a device.

What I want to do now is to reboot the device but not instantly.

Example : I want to launch a test suite that does several tests, shuts down the device, waits 1 hour and then reboots the device.

I didn't see anything in android Reference about that.
Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Do you have access to busybox?

Comment: That is simply impossible. A program cannot run if the device isn't even on. The best you could do is put the OS itself to *sleep* for an hour, but that is also nearly impossible unless you have absolute full access to the device.

Comment: @loa_in_ I didn't know this software. I'll go checking this thanks.

Comment: @OliPro007 My app has access to system commands (not root but it has better access than standard). I've checked that AlarmManagers can be active even when shut down. Do you think that with system access I can do this?

Comment: @loa_in_ I've checked about BusyBox. Unfortunately, I can't know if the device that will be used will be rooted or not so this solution isn't viable

Comment: From most threads I have read for this, you can allow the AlarmManager to automatically continue your app's behaviour *after* boot, surely you can also initiate reboot or shutdown with other stuff, however I highly doubt you can initiate a "turn on" behaviour once it has shutdown. Sure the hardware clock continues to work, but the RAM is normally completely emptied, even the kernel is not loaded anymore. You could initiate a reboot behaviour instead, but you would need to halt normal boot process for an hour, that would be really low level and not even android related afaik...

Comment: @OliPro007 I also don't think it would be related to android as I passed the day searching some tips through android sources and I still didn't see anything